# JavaScript regular expression iterator to extract groups

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

let's say we have the following text: "1 a,2 b,3 c,4 d" and the following expression: /\d (\w)/g

what we want to do is to extract a, b, c, d as denoted by the regular expression.

unfortunately "1 a,2 b,3 c,4 d".match(/\d (\w)/g) will produce an array: 1 a,2 b,3 c,4 d and RegExp.$1 will contain only the groups from the last match, i.e. RegExp.$1 == 'd'.

how can I iterate over this regex so that I can extract the groups as well... I am looking for a solution that is also memory efficient, i.e. some sort of iterator object

EDIT:
It needs to be generic. I am only providing a simple example here. One solution is to loop over the array and reapply the regex for each item without the global flag but I find this solution a bit stupid although it seems to be like the only way to do it.

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Comment: Does it need to be regex? You could also split on spaces and commas and extract that way.

Comment: yes, because I am providing only a simple example... it is more complicated than this. one solution is to reapply the regex for each match in the array but this is just stupid

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var myregexp = /\d (\w)/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    // match start: match.index
    // capturing group n: match[n]
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```

(shamelessly taken from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com))

Comment: I don't quite get this. match is just an array of all elements like 1 a, 2 b, 3 c etc... we cannot extract the capturing groups that way unless the regex is reapplied or there is API to do that...

Comment: @Pass - not when you use `exex` - match will contain the whole match as the first element, and each group as the other elements, e.g., `['1 a', 'a']`

Comment: `match[0]` is the entire match (`1 a` for example); `match[1]` is the first capturing group (`a`). This iterates over the string (see the last line of the `while` block).

Answer (score 2):

This'll work:

```
"1 a,2 b,3 c,4 d".match(/\w(?:,|$)/g).join(' '); // => "a, b, c, d"
```

If you have a need to iterate:

```
var r = /\d (\w)/g,
    s = "1 a,2 b,3 c,4 d",
    m;

while ( m = r.exec(s) ) {
    // `m` is your match, `m[1]` is the letter
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but the example is too specific.. I am looking for a generic solution because my actual code makes use of more complex regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

A shorter, simpler (though likely less efficient) solution is to use [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).  replace is unique in that it implicitly iterates over all matches *and executes a function for each match*.  Sure, you *can* use that function to actually replace text, but despite the function name that's not really required:

```
"1 a,2 b,3 c,4 d".replace(/\d (\w)/g, function(complete_match, matched_letter) {
    console.log(matched_letter);
});
```

This will log `a`, `b`, `c`, then `d` to the console.  (It will also happen to return `"undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined"`, but we don't care about that here.)

More generally, the function argument to replace [is called with the following parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
function(match, p1, p2, [...], offset, string)
```

- `match` is the matching substring.
- `p1` etc. are the match's captured groups, if any.  The groups are in order of the opening parenthesis they correspond to (i.e. leftmost first, outer first).  If the group matches multiple substrings (i.e. in a `(.)+` scenario), only the last (rightmost) substring is captured.
- `offset` is the index in the original string of this match
- `string` is the string on which `replace` was called.

Manual iteration is likely more efficient, but this method is not slow and it's shorter and (IMHO) easier to read; I tend to use this pattern over a manual loop.